# changing API data in div content with AJAX in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I created a template with React to display a live football score like that :

```
const LiveScore = () => {
const {direction} = useThemeProvider();
const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(parseInt(dayjs().format('DD')));

return (
    <Spring className="card d-flex flex-column">
        <div className="card_header d-flex flex-column g-10" style={{paddingBottom: 20}}>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <h3>{dayjs().format('MMMM')} matches</h3>
            </div>
            <Navigator active={selectedDay} setActive={setSelectedDay}/>
        </div>
        <div className="card_header d-flex flex-column g-10">
        <LeagueHeader img={english_premier} title="English Premier League" subtitle="Regular Championship" />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.grid}>
            <div className={styles.scroll}>
                <ScrollContainer height={0}>
                    <div className={`${styles.scroll_track} ${styles[direction]} track d-flex flex-column g-20`}>
                        {
                            matches.map((match, index) => (
                                <MatchMonthCard match={match} index={index} key={index}/>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                </ScrollContainer>
            </div>
            <div className={`${styles.card} ${styles[direction]}`}>
                <MatchMonthCard match={matches[2]} variant="extended"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Spring>
  )
  }
```

[the template here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTOOu.png)

Something like this page : [Click me!](https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/scores-fixtures/2024-01-16)

I'm stuck on changing results of matches automatically (get data from API) when changing date ? Any Ideas?

**EDIT**

I add code of button to switch by date :

```
const Navigator = ({active, setActive}) => {
const {theme, direction} = useThemeProvider();
const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (swiper) {
        swiper.slideToLoop(parseInt(active) - 1);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [swiper, active]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (swiper) {
        swiper.changeLanguageDirection(direction);
        swiper.update();
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [swiper, direction]);

return (
    <div className={`${styles.navigator} ${theme === 'light' ? styles.light : styles.dark}`}>
        <Swiper
            className="h-100"
            slidesPerView="auto"
            spaceBetween={10}
            centeredSlides={true}
            onSwiper={setSwiper}
            loop
            initialSlide={+active - 1}
        >
            {
                getMonthDays().map((day, index) => (
                    <SwiperSlide className={styles.slide} key={index}>
                        <div className={classNames(`${styles.navigator_item} ${styles[direction]}`, {[styles.active]: active === parseInt(day.date)})}
                             onClick={() => setActive(parseInt(day.date))}>
                            <h4 className={styles.day}>111111</h4>
                            <span className="label h6">{day.weekday}</span>
                        </div>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                ))
            }
        </Swiper>
    </div>
)
```

}

** NEW EDIT** NEW JSON FILE FOR A SINGLE CURRENT DAY :

```
{
"get": "fixtures",
"parameters": {
    "season": "2023",
    "date": "2024-01-15"
},
"errors": [],
"results": 67,
"paging": {
    "current": 1,
    "total": 1
},
"response": [
    {
        "fixture": {
            "id": 1150218,
            "referee": "Ismael Rosario Lopez Penuelas, Mexico",
            "timezone": "UTC",
            "date": "2024-01-15T00:00:00+00:00",
            "timestamp": 1705276800,
            "periods": {
                "first": 1705276800,
                "second": 1705280400
            },
            "venue": {
                "id": 1080,
                "name": "Estadio Victoria",
                "city": "Aguascalientes"
            },
            "status": {
                "long": "Match Finished",
                "short": "FT",
                "elapsed": 90
            }
        },
        "league": {
            "id": 262,
            "name": "Liga MX",
            "country": "Mexico",
            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/262.png",
            "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/mx.svg",
            "season": 2023,
            "round": "Clausura - 1"
        },
        "teams": {
            "home": {
                "id": 2288,
                "name": "Necaxa",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/2288.png",
                "winner": true
            },
            "away": {
                "id": 2283,
                "name": "Atlas",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/2283.png",
                "winner": false
            }
        },
        "goals": {
            "home": 2,
            "away": 1
        },
        "score": {
            "halftime": {
                "home": 0,
                "away": 1
            },
            "fulltime": {
                "home": 2,
                "away": 1
            },
            "extratime": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            },
            "penalty": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            }
        }
    },
    {
.....
....
```

And I get data of the current day like that:

```
const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);



const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/${date}";
const [data, setData] = useState([{}]);

const matchData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
    const d = await res.json();
    return setData(d.response);
}

useEffect(() => {
    matchData();
}, [{}]);
```

Comment: Where does the matches variable come from ? Can you provide the method that fetches them ?

Comment: @Billuc in that case I fetch them only from another file using `const` with Json format?

Comment: So matches is a prop of your component ? It isn't clear in the provided code. If it is the case, you have to "send" the date to the parent, i.e. have setSelectedDay as a prop and the useState in the parent. To make a refetch on changes to selectedDay, use the useEffect hook. Another solution, that might be simpler is simply to pass the fetch method as a prop and call it when you select a new date.

Comment: @Billuc I'm very beginner with react and JS can you provide me a code please?

Comment: Well, I was hoping you would provide me more code haha. I will make a simple repro so you can see what I mean ;)

Comment: @Billuc  thanks a lot and there are no more important code, is a static page yet with no JS code...

Comment: Here https://replit.com/@billuc/MatchScores

Comment: @Billuc a question please, how to download this project or how to run it on replit?

Comment: Ah I thought you could run the project on replit. I remade it on Stackblitz, you should be able to see it : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-k43gvs?file=src%2FApp.jsx BTW I think Example2 is better

Comment: @Billuc Thanks a lot for your great help, but a such solution I can do it, the problem is that I can't change the style of  react template, for example, I can't use `<button onClick={() => setDate(date.add(-1, 'd'))}>Previous</button>` to switch the date, but I must use like template `<Navigator active={selectedDay} setActive={setSelectedDay}/>`?

Comment: I don't see how that is a problem. You can take inspiration on `Fetcher.jsx` for example. Here I use `<MatchesDisplay date={date} setDate={setDate}>` which is similar, and I trigger the fetching via the useEffect hook.

Comment: I can modify my code to make it more similar to yours if needed

Comment: @Billuc yes but If you can me i wish that will help a lot

Comment: Maybe like this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-k43gvs?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FLiveScore.jsx

Comment: @Billuc sorry for the delay and your solution help me a lot and is works but not that what I want exactly, my json data is different to yourz, I mean I don't have fixtures for everyday in one json file like your code but I have to fetch data for every day alone using url and `fetch()` I make some changes in my topic to get well what I search for?

Comment: @Billuc my idea is to get livescore of the current day when clicking this day and the next day when I click the date of next day but get data not from the same json but a json called of specified date in URL without refreshing the page as what U did in your example?

Comment: well, I see you used a useEffect hook to fetch data. However, you messed up the dependencies (the array after the function). The date should be in there so that each time the date changes, you will call the matchData function again. I advise you to pass the date as an argument to the matchData function and build the url in it. As for the structure of the JSON, it is up to you to extract the right information. I gave you a minimal example for inspiration :)

Comment: @Billuc please change your answer to a feedback the I can approve it as a solution to my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following our conversation in the comments :

To execute an action when a value is changed, you have to use the useEffect hook. This hook has 2 arguments : The first is a callback (the action to effectuate when the value changes) and the second is a list of the dependencies to watch.

In your case, the dependency is selectedDay and the callback is a call to matchData. However, matchData should be modified to use the correct URL corresponding to the selected day.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-k43gvs?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FLiveScore.jsx) is a simple repro.